# Going to Specific tab in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, report, oracleforms

I have 3 radio button A ,B, C
and I have 3 tab page in the canvas A, B,C.

My Requirement is if user select radio A and press Submit button then tab A Should get activated and my cursor got to tab A.

Answer (score 3):

If it is enabled and visible then you can use the following commands:

```
go_item('blockname.itemname');
```

or

```
go_block('blockname');
```

If you don't need to go to a specific item then use the second command go_block.

Answer (score 1):

To enable a tab page:

```
set_tab_page_property('TAB_PAGE_NAME',enabled,property_true);
```

If the tab page was not visible you should make it visible first:

```
set_tab_page_property('TAB_PAGE_NAME',visible,property_true);
```

In order to navigate to that tab page, the easiest way to accomplish that is by going to a navigable item that is in that tab page:

```
go_item('ITEM_IN_THE_TAB_PAGE');
```

Comment: In many cases it should be enough to use Go_Item() to navigate to an item on the tap page. This as usually depends how the tab pages are set up in your form.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the tab page as top most using set_tab_page_property(top_most_tab_page,'tab_page_name'). after that use go_item('block_name.item_name');

Comment: Would upvote this except that you don't have to do *both* of these actions - one or the other is usually sufficient.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, if we must do both the actions, for the navigation and visibility of the tab page to be proper. we are not sure, items are directly placed in the tab page canvas or stacked canvas placed on the tab page canvas.

Comment: that's why you would choose an item that's on the tab page canvas - if you can navigate to an item on the correct tab, that's all you need. Otherwise, you can use `set_tab_page_property`. But you don't need both.

Comment: No jeffrey. if we are using the stacked canvas, simply if we use go_item, it will go to the item. but the top most Tab page will be the old page before the cursor exists. Pls try this. surely you will face problem if you dont set top most tab page.

Comment: "if we are using the stacked canvas"... I think we have a language barrier.

Answer (score 0):

here is the easiest way to do this

In the following code, I supposed that the radio button name is: RADIO_BTN and it's value is 'A'

1. open submit button properties and set 'keyboard navigation'= No and 'mouse navigation'= No
2. on tab A create a dummy item (not database item) and name it A, with width=0 and height=0 so the user will not see it, or use a real item name on tab A
3. open trigger when_button_pressed on submit button and write the following code.

   IF :RADIO_BTN = 'A' THEN /*replace this with your radio_btn name and value */
       GO_ITEM('A'); /*go to dummy item in tab A or to real item in tab A */
   END IF;