# Order tab page in oracle forms?

Tags: oracleforms

I have four tab page A,B,C,D.
I have a master and detail views and the tab pages are on detail view.
When i click on the detail views, the tap page who have the focus is the first tap page. When i close it and reopen again the the tab page which have the focus is the last tab page which has the focus not necessary the first one.
how can i set a default tab page ?

Comment: I do not remember this for sure as last time I worked with Forms in 2013. Look at the When-New-Form-Instance trigger and set the tab page there. This trigger will not work when opening form from form, passing parameters to open multiple forms, etc... In this case I think you need to use When-Form-Navigate. Look at the documentation. Also, there are tab triggers that will help you to navigate between tabs.

Comment: this link may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833948/going-to-specific-tab-in-oracle-forms